# catkin_make error: ImportError: No module named 'error'

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, i am a beginner in ROS i have this error every time i do a catkin_make

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/genpy/cmake/../../../lib/genpy/genmsg_py.py", line 44, in <module>
    import genpy.generator
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . message import Message, SerializationError, DeserializationError, MessageException, struct_I
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 44, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from error import *
ImportError: No module named 'error'
```

and after a lot of googling i figured that the problem is because of the PYTHONPATH.

so to check my PYTHONPATH is did

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

and i got

```
/home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

i think the reason behind the problem is the "/python3/dist-package"
how do i change it ?
i tried adding the path manually in ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

but still every time i do`echo $PYTHONPATH` i get

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

how do i solve this ?
Please HELP !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340321/catkin_make-error:-importerror:-no-module-named-%27error%27/) by [RoboNerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41848/robonerd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2019-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i was able to solve my error by deleting the content inside the `BUILD` folder and then do `catkin_make`. So the problem is solved for now and also there was a folder named name `python3` in `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3` which reappeared every time i do `catkin_make` no matter how many times i deleted the folder manually. This time i deleted and it never reappeared. I even removed the manually added `PYTHONPATH` in my `~/.bashrc` so now the `echo $PYTHONPATH` is `/home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` which I believe is the correct `PYTHONPATH`. Thanks @gvdhoorn & @Abhishekpg111 for your suggestions.

---

Originally posted by [RoboNerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41848/robonerd/) with karma: 30 on 2019-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try adding export PYTHONPATH="/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

---

Originally posted by [Abhishekpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/50018/abhishekpg/) with karma: 195 on 2019-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboNerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41848/robonerd/) on 2019-12-20**:
it doesn't solve the issue, the error persists. However every time i do `echo $PYTHONPATH` i get `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-20**:
Yes, I would not have expected this to work.

@RoboNerd: can you explain why we see mentions of Python 3 in your `PYTHONPATH`? Kinetic does not support Python 3 natively, and while it is possible to use it, problems like these are typically seen when things are not correctly configured.

Do you have Anaconda installed by any chance?

**Comment by [RoboNerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41848/robonerd/) on 2019-12-20**:
No, i have not installed Anaconda and i don't know how there are mentions of Python 3 in my `PYTHONPATH` But i was able to rectify my error by deleting the content inside the `BUILD` folder and then do `catkin_make`. So the problem is solved for now and also there was a folder named name `python3` in `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3` which reappeared every time i do `catkin_make` no matter how many times i deleted the folder manually. This time i deleted and it never reappeared. I even removed the manually added `PYTHONPATH` in my `~/.bashrc` so now the `echo $PYTHONPATH` is `/home/username/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` which I believe is the correct `PYTHONPATH`. Thanks @gvdhoorn & @Abhishekpg111 for your suggestions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-20**:
Ok. Good to hear things now work.

Suggestion: post your last comment as an answer and accept your own answer.

I've unchecked the answer by @Abhishekpg111 as it's not the real answer.

**Comment by [RoboNerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41848/robonerd/) on 2019-12-20**:
sure, I'll do that.